# Webservice.wsdl and credentials

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, wsdl, credentials

So I've got a bit of an issue I'm trying to work through. Perhaps some Flex guru could assist?

I have a WebService instance that attempts to load a WSDL file from our JBoss Application Server. If I do something like this:

```
webService = new WebService();
webService.destination = WebService.DEFAULT_DESTINATION_HTTP;
webService.wsdl = "http://<removed>/services/ApiService?wsdl";
webService.loadWSDL();
```

everything works fine. The WSDL is loaded successfully and the application can invoke methods against the web service.

The issue is when I need to add some HTTP authentication to the mix:

```
webService.setCredentials(userName, password);
```

this line ends up throwing an error stating that credentials are only supported on HTTPS. Ok fair enough, I want to use secure HTTPS anyway!

So then I tried to change it up to this...

```
webService = new WebService();
webService.destination = WebService.DEFAULT_DESTINATION_HTTPS;
webService.wsdl = "https://<removed>/services/ApiService?wsdl";
webService.setCredentials(userName, password);
webService.loadWSDL();
```

and now the WebService instance cannot load the WSDL. The error received is:

> [FaultEvent fault=[RPC Fault faultString="HTTP request error" faultCode="Server.Error.Request" faultDetail="Unable to load WSDL. If currently online, please verify the URI and/or format of the WSDL (https://<removed>/services/ApiService?wsdl)"] messageId="6905CC5B-5317-C4B3-2D12-84647EE648A7" type="fault" bubbles=false cancelable=true eventPhase=2]

I can reach this URI in the browser just fine and it returns the WSDL as expected.

I am not a Flex guy (learning) but instead a Java developer. I am trying out Flex as a potential client to our system but this has caused me all kinds of grief today. Google doesn't appear to have any quick answers for me and I am a bit stumped.

First question on StackOverflow so hopefully this gets a bite somewhere and helps some other poor Java dev staying late in the office on a Friday night :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://groups.google.com/group/flex_india/browse_thread/thread/2d22fc22320db026?pli=1) seems to be related to your question. We are planning to use https in the future, so I'm curious to know the solution of your problem.

Comment: In case that link no longer works... the problem is that I am using a self-signed certificate which pops up a browser warning. Flex will not allow the application to view the WSDL against an untrusted certificate. Once I trusted the certificate I could use the WSDL.

Thanks!