# [RPC Fault faultString="HTTP request error" faultCode="Server.Error.Request" faultDetail="Unable to load WSDL

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, builder

following the code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">

   <mx:WebService id="DirectoryService" 
        useProxy="false"  
        wsdl="http://cmuicds.rutgers.edu/uicds/core/ws/services/DirectoryService?wsdl"> 
    <mx:operation name="GetIncidentList"                
        makeObjectsBindable="true" 
        resultFormat="object" 
        result="onResult(event)" 
        fault="onFault(event)"/>
   </mx:WebService>

    <mx:ApplicationControlBar dock="true">
    <mx:Button id="button"
            label="Get incidents from web service"
            click="button_click()"/>
       <mx:ComboBox id="cmb" dataProvider="{incedents}" labelField="name" width="241" height="24"/>
       <mx:TextArea id="textArea" x="10" y="40" width="616" height="61"/>
    </mx:ApplicationControlBar>

   <mx:Script>
       <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import flash.utils.ByteArray;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.rpc.soap.mxml.WebService;

        [Bindable] private var incedents:ArrayCollection;
        private var flag:Boolean;
        //[Bindable] private var arr:Array = new Array("http://uicds.org/DirectoryService", "GetIncidentListRequest");
        //private var byte:ByteArray;

        private function button_click():void 
        {
            //DirectoryService.GetIncidentList("http://uicds.org/DirectoryService", "GetIncidentListRequest").send();

            //DirectoryService.port = 443;
            DirectoryService.endpointURI = "https://cmuicds.rutgers.edu:443/uicds/core/ws/services/DirectoryServiceService";
            DirectoryService.GetIncidentList("GetIncidentListRequest");

            flag = DirectoryService.canLoadWSDL();
            Alert.show("Testing....." + flag); 

        } 

         private function onResult(evt:ResultEvent):void 
         {
            incedents = evt.result as ArrayCollection;
            Alert.show("Is data comming in? " + incedents);
            textArea.text = ObjectUtil.toString(evt.result);
        }

         private function onFault(evt:FaultEvent):void 
         {
            Alert.show(evt.fault.faultString);                
         }

       ]]>
   </mx:Script>

</mx:Application>
```

when i run it it gives me a following error:
[RPC Fault faultString="HTTP request error" faultCode="Server.Error.Request" faultDetail="Unable to load WSDL. If currently online, please verify the URI and/or format of the WSDL (http://cmuicds.rutgers.edu/uicds/core/ws/services/DirectoryService?wsdl)"]

I really need help on this.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I type the url "http://cmuicds.rutgers.edu/uicds/core/ws/services/DirectoryService?wsdl" into my browser, the HTTP GET response prompts me for a username and password.

Chances are that an HTTP POST which is what mx:WebService is using is facing the same obstacle too. I believe you need to address that authentication problem.

Comment: The url is protected i do have user name and password.

Comment: This is the part of the method that i am calling from web service:<wsdl:operation name="GetIncidentList">
<wsdl:input message="tns:GetIncidentListRequest" name="GetIncidentListRequest"></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:GetIncidentListResponse" name="GetIncidentListResponse"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>

Comment: Well, I don't even think your app is getting to stage where it can actually invoke a web operation because your server is kicking you out because you have zero authentication. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616759/webservice-wsdl-and-credentials and see the usage of setCredentials. I believe you are getting "Unable to load WSDL" because the server won't let you have access to it unless you provide the appropriate username and password.